# How to vectorize the antenna arrayfactor expression in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, signal-processing, vectorization, telecommunication

I have the antenna array factor expression here:

[image: Antenna Array factor]

I have coded the array factor expression as given below:

```
lambda = 1;
M = 100;N = 200; %an M x N array
dx = 0.3*lambda; %inter-element spacing in x direction
m = 1:M; 
xm = (m - 0.5*(M+1))*dx; %element positions in x direction

dy = 0.4*lambda;
n = 1:N;
yn = (n - 0.5*(N+1))*dy;

thetaCount = 360; % no of theta values

thetaRes = 2*pi/thetaCount; % theta resolution

thetas = 0:thetaRes:2*pi-thetaRes; % theta values

phiCount = 180;

phiRes = pi/phiCount;

phis = -pi/2:phiRes:pi/2-phiRes;

cmpWeights = rand(N,M); %complex Weights

AF = zeros(phiCount,thetaCount); %Array factor

tic
for i = 1:phiCount
    for j = 1:thetaCount

        for p = 1:M
            for q = 1:N

                AF(i,j) = AF(i,j) + cmpWeights(q,p)*exp((2*pi*1j/lambda)*(xm(p)*sin(thetas(j))*cos(phis(i)) + yn(q)*sin(thetas(j))*sin(phis(i))));

            end
        end
    end
end
```

How can I vectorize the code for calculating the Array Factor (AF).

I want the line:

```
AF(i,j) = AF(i,j) + cmpWeights(q,p)*exp((2*pi*1j/lambda)*(xm(p)*sin(thetas(j))*cos(phis(i)) + yn(q)*sin(thetas(j))*sin(phis(i))));
```

to be written in vectorized form (by modifying the for loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1: Full-throttle**

The innermost nested loop generates this every iteration - **`cmpWeights(q,p)*exp((2*pi*1j/lambda)*(xm(p)*sin(thetas(j))*cos(phis(i)) + yn(q)*sin(thetas(j))*sin(phis(i))))`**, which are to summed up iteratively to give us the final output in `AF`.

Let's call the **`exp(....`** part as `B`. Now, `B` basically has two parts, one is the scalar **`(2*pi*1j/lambda)`** and the other part 
**`(xm(p)*sin(thetas(j))*cos(phis(i)) + yn(q)*sin(thetas(j))*sin(phis(i)))`** that is formed from the variables that are dependent on
the four iterators used in the original loopy versions - **`i,j,p,q`**. Let's call this other part as `C` for easy reference later on.

Let's put all that into perspective:

- Loopy version had **`AF(i,j) = AF(i,j) + cmpWeights(q,p)*exp((2*pi*1j/lambda)*(xm(p)*sin(thetas(j))*cos(phis(i)) + yn(q)*sin(thetas(j))*sin(phis(i))))`**, which is now equivalent to `AF(i,j) = AF(i,j) + cmpWeights(q,p)*B`, where **`B = exp((2*pi*1j/lambda)*(xm(p)*sin(thetas(j))*cos(phis(i)) + yn(q)*sin(thetas(j))*sin(phis(i))))`**.
- `B` could be simplified to **`B = exp((2*pi*1j/lambda)* C)`**, where **`C = (xm(p)*sin(thetas(j))*cos(phis(i)) + yn(q)*sin(thetas(j))*sin(phis(i)))`**.
- `C` would depend on the iterators - `i,j,p,q`.

So, after porting onto a vectorized way, it would end up as this -

```
%// 1) Define vectors corresponding to iterators used in the loopy version
I = 1:phiCount;
J = 1:thetaCount;
P = 1:M;
Q = 1:N;

%// 2) Create vectorized version of C using all four vector iterators
mult1 = bsxfun(@times,sin(thetas(J)),cos(phis(I)).'); %//'
mult2 = bsxfun(@times,sin(thetas(J)),sin(phis(I)).'); %//'

mult1_xm = bsxfun(@times,mult1(:),permute(xm,[1 3 2]));
mult2_yn = bsxfun(@times,mult2(:),yn);
C_vect = bsxfun(@plus,mult1_xm,mult2_yn);

%// 3) Create vectorized version of B using vectorized C
B_vect = reshape(exp((2*pi*1j/lambda)*C_vect),phiCount*thetaCount,[]);

%// 4) Final output as matrix multiplication between vectorized versions of B and C
AF_vect = reshape(B_vect*cmpWeights(:),phiCount,thetaCount);
```

---

**Approach #2: Less-memory intensive**

This second approach would reduce the memory traffic and it uses the distributive property of exponential - **`exp(A+B) = exp(A)*exp(B)`**.

Now, the original loopy version was this -

```
AF(i,j) = AF(i,j) + cmpWeights(q,p)*exp((2*pi*1j/lambda)*...
    (xm(p)*sin(thetas(j))*cos(phis(i)) + yn(q)*sin(thetas(j))*sin(phis(i))))
```

So, after using the distributive property, we would endup with something like this -

```
K = (2*pi*1j/lambda)
part1 = K*xm(p)*sin(thetas(j))*cos(phis(i));
part2 = K*yn(q)*sin(thetas(j))*sin(phis(i));
AF(i,j) = AF(i,j) + cmpWeights(q,p)*exp(part1)*exp(part2);
```

Thus, the relevant vectorized approach would become something like this -

```
%// 1) Define vectors corresponding to iterators used in the loopy version
I = 1:phiCount;
J = 1:thetaCount;
P = 1:M;
Q = 1:N;

%// 2) Define the constant used at the start of EXP() call
K = (2*pi*1j/lambda);

%// 3) Perform the sine-cosine operations part1 & part2 in vectorized manners
mult1 = K*bsxfun(@times,sin(thetas(J)),cos(phis(I)).'); %//'
mult2 = K*bsxfun(@times,sin(thetas(J)),sin(phis(I)).'); %//'

%// Perform exp(part1) & exp(part2) in vectorized manners
part1_vect = exp(bsxfun(@times,mult1(:),xm));
part2_vect = exp(bsxfun(@times,mult2(:),yn));

%// Perform multiplications with cmpWeights for final output
AF = reshape(sum((part1_vect*cmpWeights.').*part2_vect,2),phiCount,[])
```

---

**Quick Benchmarking**

Here are the runtimes with the input data listed in the question for the original loopy approach and proposed approach #2  -

```
---------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 358.081507 seconds.

---------------------------- With Proposed Approach #2
Elapsed time is 0.405038 seconds.
```

The runtimes suggests a crazy performance improvement with **`Approach #2`**!

Answer (score 1):

The basic trick is to figure out what things are constant, and what things depend on the subscript term - and therefore are matrix terms.

*Within* the sum:

- `C(n,m)` is a matrix
- `2π/λ` is a constant
- `sin(θ)cos(φ)` is a constant
- `x(m)` and `y(n)` are vectors

So the two things I would do are:

1. Expand the `xm` and `ym` into matrices using `meshgrid()`
2. Take all the constant term stuff outside the loop.

Like this:

```
...

piFactor = 2 * pi * 1j / lambda;

[xgrid, ygrid] = meshgrid(xm, ym);                                       % xgrid and ygrid will be size (N, M)

for i = 1:phiCount
    for j = 1:thetaCount

        xFactor = sin(thetas(j)) * cos(phis(i));
        yFactor = sin(thetas(j)) * sin(phis(i));

        expFactor = exp(piFactor * (xgrid * xFactor + ygrid * yFactor)); % expFactor is size (N, M)

        elements = cmpWeights .* expFactor;                              % elements of sum, size (N, M)

        AF(i, j) = AF(i, j) + sum(elements(:));                          % sum and then integrate.

    end
end
```

You could probably figure out how to vectorise the outer loop too, but hopefully that gives you a starting point.